# How can I find a collection of tweets?

Tags: twitter, information-retrieval

Is there any data sets which includes tweets? I am doing a project in information retrieval and I need a large set of tweets.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That one could be helpfull http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/twitter-census-developer-tools-mapping-from-twitter-user-search-
And you can use Twitter API to retrieve fresh data.

Comment: I already seen this, this doesn't include the actual tweets.

Comment: https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/display/forward/Dataset-UDI-TwitterCrawl-Aug2012

Comment: I was looking for something like this. but appreciate your help. I'll give you the best answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the collection I was looking for here:

https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/display/forward/Dataset-UDI-TwitterCrawl-Aug2012